# Submit button in HTML forms

Tags: html, button, submit

I'm trying to create a HTML form, and in the end I'm adding a submit button:

```
<submit submitLabel="Save"/>
```

Is there an attribute that can be configured so that when pressing the button not only saves the data in the form, but it redirects to another HTML form? Perhaps to create a workflow between HTML forms?

Comment: You need to do this on the server with whatever language you're using, or you could submit the form to a page with a redirect meta tag.

Answer (score 1):

clicking a submit button inside a form issuing a POST/GET request to the page you defined in the `<form action="_____"`

you can put your second form in the other page (the page you defined in the `action` attribute)

or even better - you can use AJAX, and avoid reloading the page

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to do it, but it depends also with what language you work. HTML alone doesn't cut it. You need a server side language as well, such as ASP or PHP

When I use php, i simply create a form and make sure the action is marked to the next page. There i can put the next form in, but I can process also the information I just picked up.

See example below

```
     <form method="post" action="the place of the next form plus where processing happens.php">

     put here your fields

     <button name="btn_moveon" type="submit" >Go further to next page</button> 
     </form>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I think the major issue was that I was only using HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through code or the ACTION attribute of the form tag.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't such an element. You must do this on server side, with whatever programming language the server runs (eg. PHP, ASP, etc.).